# Incorrect height calculation when CSS property line-height is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, css

I need to exactly set the height of a parent `ul` element dependent on the included `li`'s. But as soon as I have a `line-height` CSS property with fractional digits the whole calculation isn't correct anmyore. Sometimes the calculated height is sometimes too large and sometimes too small (e.g. [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/M93gZ/) 1px in Firefox). When it is a larger list it often differs by several pixels. And when settings the height of the parent `ul` it happens that it is too small for its content.

How could I calculate exact values, even when `line-height` is set?

Answer (score 4):

If you target the recent browsers only you can use `window.getComputedStyle` that returns all the css properties as they are painted on the screen.

Comment: Nice answer (and upvoted), but I am looking for a more browser independent solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a stupid solution because I'm terrible and lazy, but here is my crazy work-around:

In the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function fixmyheight(h) {
   document.getElementById('fixme').style.height = h + "px";
}
</script>
```

And then in the body:

```
<ul id="fixme">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Sorry, I screwed that up at first.   Fixed now.

Comment: I am sorry, but that doesn't make any sense as the thing I want to calculate correctly is `h` in your example. Setting the height then is obvious.

Comment: Actually, sorry.  That writes the height.  My fault.  Here is how to read the height: var myh = document.getElementById('fixme').offsetHeight; ... after you detect it being wrong, you can write the height with the code given before... or if that doesn't work, you can change the <ul>'s overflow property to "hidden"... or you can tweak the properties of the <li>s

Comment: No problem, I really appreciate that you are trying to help. I just like to calculate the exact height of the <ul> so that all <li>'s exactly fit in there ... not as simple as I thought at the first time. Simply getting the offset height of the <ul> does not work when some CSS specifies an other height. And I also don't like to touch the <li> CSS properties.

Comment: Well, 1em = 16px, so 1.3em=20.8px, right?  If it is anti-aliasing like that, and you are just counting 21px for every <li>, it's possible that it is screwing up on account of that?  Or perhaps it is rounding, but you are anti-aliasing.  I'm assuming you've already played around with that, but since you are not using any li borders, margins, etc., that would be my first guess as to why it is going haywire.  I'm very new to making web sites, but that's my $0.02.