# Wrong height in Firefox (canvas drawings)

Tags: jquery, css, html5-canvas

I need a script drawing in canvas red boxes side by side with html-table-tds which is on the right...

It is how it is done:
http://jsfiddle.net/KaDnQ/1/

Html:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <table class="t2" border="1">
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>6</td></tr>
        <tr><td>7</td></tr>
        <tr><td>8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>9</td></tr>
        <tr><td>10</td></tr>
        <tr><td>11</td></tr>
        <tr><td>12</td></tr>
        <tr><td>13</td></tr>
        <tr><td>14</td></tr>
        <tr><td>15</td></tr>
        <tr><td>16</td></tr>
        <tr><td>10</td></tr>
        <tr><td>11</td></tr>
        <tr><td>12</td></tr>
        <tr><td>13</td></tr>
        <tr><td>14</td></tr>
        <tr><td>15</td></tr>
        <tr><td>16</td></tr>
        <tr><td>10</td></tr>
        <tr><td>11</td></tr>
        <tr><td>12</td></tr>
        <tr><td>13</td></tr>
        <tr><td>14</td></tr>
        <tr><td>15</td></tr>
        <tr><td>16</td></tr>
        <tr><td>10</td></tr>
        <tr><td>11</td></tr>
        <tr><td>12</td></tr>
        <tr><td>13</td></tr>
        <tr><td>14</td></tr>
        <tr><td>15</td></tr>
        <tr><td>16</td></tr>
        <tr><td>10</td></tr>
        <tr><td>11</td></tr>
        <tr><td>12</td></tr>
        <tr><td>13</td></tr>
        <tr><td>14</td></tr>
        <tr><td>15</td></tr>
        <tr><td>16</td></tr>
        <tr><td>10</td></tr>
        <tr><td>11</td></tr>
        <tr><td>12</td></tr>
        <tr><td>13</td></tr>
        <tr><td>14</td></tr>
        <tr><td>15</td></tr>
        <tr><td>16</td></tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td valign="top"><canvas id="x"></canvas></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 30px;
}

.t2 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.t2 td {
     padding: 5px;
     text-align: center;
}

canvas {
    border: 1px dashed green;
}
```

Js:

```
var canvasWidth = $(".t2").outerWidth()*3;
var canvasHeight = $(".t2").outerHeight();
var c = document.getElementById("x");
var c2 = c.getContext("2d");

c.width = canvasWidth;
c.height = canvasHeight;

$('.t2 td:odd').each(function() {

    var cur = $(this);
    var topOffset = 0;
    var shouldCount = true;
    var h = $(this).outerHeight();

    $('.t2 td').each(function() {    
        if (shouldCount) {
            topOffset += h;

            if (cur.is(this)) {
                topOffset -= h;
                shouldCount = false;
            }
        }
    });

    c2.fillStyle = '#f00';
    c2.beginPath();
    c2.moveTo(0, topOffset);
    c2.lineTo(25, topOffset);
    c2.lineTo(25, topOffset+h);
    c2.lineTo(0, topOffset+h);
    c2.closePath();
    c2.fill();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KaDnQ/1/

It is how it looks like in Chrome (correct):
[image: correct rendering in Chrome: side by side]

The problem is that lower boxes in **Firefox** are offseted from their "parents" tds.
[image: lower boxes are offseted]

**What is the reason of wrong rendering in Firefox and how to fix?**

---

Update: wrong rendering appears on **FF 19 (mac)** and **IE 9 (win)**!

Comment: Looks fine in my Firefox 18.0.2

Comment: Me too, looks ok on 19.0.

Comment: weird... I have FF on Mac

Comment: I also asked one my friend on win to check: the bug appears in IE 9! http://monosnap.com/image/MoGyhxaYctg9WGFimqlTIfznX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spending much time on researches & debugging, I am ready to answer my own question:

The problem was that "the container height does NOT always equals to the sum of all elements inside".
Found out, that it is because "**line-height**" property.

Similar problem was described here:
[Incorrect height calculation when CSS property line-height is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136264/incorrect-height-calculation-when-css-property-line-height-is-set)

Here it is a little modified, working solution (Chrome & FF tested):
http://jsfiddle.net/BgYpw/3/

The idea how to fix:
to sum the height/outerHeight of all elements inside container and apply that value to canvas.height.

In the example above it is done simply so:

```
c.height = $('#le div').length * $('#le div:first').outerHeight();
```

Count of all elements inside is multiplied with the outerHeight of first.
That solution does not go if height of elements inside could differ.
It that case, you can get the height by doing **$.each** loop and summing heights particularly...

Hope my reply will save hours for somebody :)